# MS GRAPH REST API - add event error when adding attendees

Tags: rest, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an event into the shared calendar (meeting room) and I get an error when trying to put myself as an attendee. However the event is created into the meeting room's calendar but not into my own (the attendee's calendar).

Preconditions:
User A = logged user (user_A@company.com)
User B = target meeting room (user_B@company.com)

User A has permissions to write into User's B calendar.

This is the call request url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_B@company.com/events
```

Request body:

```
{
  "iCalUId": "user_B@company.com",
  "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
  "isReminderOn": true,
  "subject": "test",
  "start" : {
      "dateTime": "2017-02-22T10:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "end" : {
      "dateTime": "2017-02-22T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Europe/Prague"
  },
  "attendees":[
      {
          "emailAddress": { "address": "user_A@company.com" },
          "type": "required",
          "status" : { "response": "accepted" }      
      }
  ]
}
```

The response:

```
client-request-id: 12542206-5490-4d21-b5e8-e9a32b1d3fc1
content-type: application/json
cache-control: private
request-id: 12542206-5490-4d21-b5e8-e9a32b1d3fc1
Status Code: 500
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: Argument#1 (id) shouldn't be null.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "12542206-5490-4d21-b5e8-e9a32b1d3fc1",
            "date": "2017-02-22T08:20:53"
        }
    }
}
```

The error is not really informative for me because there is no ID parameter described in the API for the call. 
And I also think there should be an email sent to User A once the event is created and the user is added as an attendee. I do not get the email.
May it be caused by some AD misconfiguration? Or what do I miss here, please?

P.S., 
If I add the event into my own calendar and add the meeting room as an attendee, it works fine, email is sent and event accepted. There is a delay tho, the event appears in the meeting room's calendar approx 20 seconds later which is the reason I need to do it vice versa as described in the question!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `iCalUId` is not writable, so try leaving that out.

Also, just to confirm, can you do what you're trying to do via Outlook?

As an aside, assuming you get this working, keep in mind that this will result in the meeting having the conference room as the organizer, and yourself as an attendee.

Comment: I got the same result when iCalUid was left out. 
Yes, I can do it in the Outlook. 
I know that the meeting room will be the organizer, this is ok. 

It works fine if I leave out all attendees, the event is created with no issues. It is only related to attendees in some way. 

The reason why we do it this way is that we need to have the event in the meeting room's calendar right after the post request. Then we can see instantly that there is an event - the meeting room has been reserved already.

Comment: Ok. Given that you get a 500, this is most likely a bug. I can reproduce it, so let me see what our devs can add here :)

Comment: Great, if it is a bug, it was a pleasure to find it. ;) Please, update me when you receive some answer. Thank you.

Comment: I've filed this as a bug and will update here once I have more to report.